# DataGenerator(Sequence) without resize

Tags: python, generator

I created a class `DataGenerator(Sequence)`which defines the `batch_size`, `batch_x` and `batch_y`. `batch_x` are batches of images (which come from `x_set`, a list of file paths to the images) which are read in by `imread`, resized by `resize` and divided by 255 in order to get values between 0 and 1. `batch_y` are labels for these images which come form `y_set`, a list which contains all labels.

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array([resize(imread(file_name), (64, 128)) for file_name in batch_x])
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

Because this generator works but takes very long on Colab, I resized the images before. So, that is not necessary anymore and I would now like to modify the `DataGenerator` and leave the `resize` function out. This is my code for `DataGenerator_withoutresize(Sequence)`:

```
class DataGenerator_withoutresize(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array([(imread(file_name) for file_name in batch_x])
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

Is this code correct?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to know whether it is correct, run it, step through it in the debugger looking at variables, etc....

Comment: How would you do this in that case?

Comment: How did you run it and test it before the change?  Test it again after the change.  Write a unit test.  Stop in the debugger and see what it does line by line.  If you are dealing with too much data to check in the debugger, well, you'll check that in the unit test.  But you can spot check to make sure that things are doing more or less what you expect....

Comment: Thank you :-) Yes, the problem was that I did not get the data on my drive. But it is now solved ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used this code, which is working for me:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = [imread(file_name) for file_name in batch_x]
        batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```